# Access environment variables passed in docker run from supervisor child process

Tags: docker, supervisord

I'm running a docker container with the following command:

```
docker run -it -e CustomEnvVariable="val123" -p 80:80 imagename
```

The image has [supervisor](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor) running with the following conf file for my app:

```
[program:myapp]
command=/usr/bin/dotnet /root/myapp/myapp.dll
directory=/root/myapp/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myapp.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myapp.out.log
environment=ASPNETCORE__ENVIRONMENT=Production
stopsignal=INT
user=root
```

How can I access `CustomEnvVariable` from within myapp after supervisor launches it?

I tried the following value in the `conf` file `environment` value:

```
environment=ASPNETCORE__ENVIRONMENT=Production,CustomEnvVariable=%(ENV_CustomEnvVariable)s
```

but I would received this error when restarting supervisor:

```
Restarting supervisor: Error: 
Format string 'ASPNETCORE__ENVIRONMENT=Production,CustomEnvVariable="%(ENV_CustomEnvVariable)s"' 
for 'environment' contains names which cannot be expanded
```

Some more information:

Using supervisor version: 3.0 (install via `apt-get install supervisor -y`).

I confirmed that the value of `CustomEnvVariable` is reaching the container by checking the output of `echo $CustomEnvVariable`.

I did a quick scan of all the environment variables available to from the app, here are the results:

```
{
  "LC_ADDRESS": "",
  "SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME": "myapp",
  "LC_MONETARY": "",
  "LC_MESSAGES": "",
  "LC_NAME": "",
  "SUPERVISOR_ENABLED": "1",
  "SUPERVISOR_SERVER_URL": "unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock",
  "LC_COLLATE": "",
  "ASPNETCORE__ENVIRONMENT": "Production",
  "SUPERVISOR_GROUP_NAME": "myapp",
  "LANG": "",
  "LC_NUMERIC": "",
  "LANGUAGE": "",
  "LC_PAPER": "",
  "LC_IDENTIFICATION": "",
  "LC_CTYPE": "",
  "LC_MEASUREMENT": "",
  "TERM": "xterm",
  "LC_TIME": "",
  "LC_ALL": "",
  "PATH": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin",
  "LC_TELEPHONE": "",
  "PWD": "/"
}
```

Comment: Have you checked it's definitely being set / passed in (by echoing it?). Also try single quoting it instead of double on the `docker run...`.

Comment: Confirmed that when I run bash inside the container I get the value passed in via `docker run -e` when I execute `echo $CustomEnvVariable`. So it's getting to the container for sure.

Comment: What version of supervisor?

Comment: Using supervisor version: 3.0 (install via `apt-get install supervisor -y`).

Comment: Environment expansion is only available in > 3.2 - https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/599.

Comment: Thank you. That was a lot of wasted effort on my part. I assumed `apt-get` would have the latest version... Could you post this as an answer so I can mark it? Also, any idea how I can install it using apt-get or must I use pip?

Comment: Run `apt-cache policy supervisor` to check what's available. If it didn't download then probably pip or the releases from github maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is correct, but environment expansion is only available in version > 3.2 of supervisor, [as per this github issue](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/599).

Comment: FYI, upon further usage, it seems the environment variables are accessible by the child process __without__ having to do the variable expansion as outlined in my answer.